# Как улучшить асинхронный постоянно работающий python код?

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, telegram-bot, классы

Всем здравствуйте, я пишу телеграм ботов на python и библиотеке aiogram, перехожу на PostgreSQL при помощи библиотеки asyncpg. Так же добавил в свой код классы, которыми никогда до этого не пользовался, подскажите пожалуйста что можно улучшить в моём коде?

```
import asyncpg
from config import *

from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot, types

import config


bot = Bot(config.bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


class DataBase:
    """Класс для управления базой данных"""

    async def get_user_info(self, user_id):
        connection = await asyncpg.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name, port=port)

        result = await connection.fetch('''
            select * from users where t_id = $1
        ''', user_id)

        await connection.close()

        return result[0]

    async def add_user(self, user_id, user_name):
        connection = await asyncpg.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name, port=port)

        await connection.fetch('''
            insert into users(t_id, username) values($1, $2)
        ''', user_id, user_name)

        await connection.close()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state='*')  # Хендлер
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    db = DataBase()
    user_info = await db.get_user_info(user_id=message.from_user.id)
    if len(user_info):
        print(user_info)
        text = f'''
{user_info['t_id']}
{user_info['username']}
        '''
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
    else:
        await db.add_user(user_id=message.from_user.id, user_name=message.from_user.first_name)
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Регистрация успешна!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Хочу побольше узнать как можно задействовать классы в работе с БД и про библиотеку asyncpg ( потому что до этого я использовал sqlite3, поэтому тут мне немного сложно разобраться )

Comment: Классы, как правило, нужны если у вас в программе несколько похожих объектов, а так просто их применять это нарушение принципа "простое лучше сложного". А для работы с бд может лучше отдельный модуль.

Comment: Согласен, но мне в моём другом [обращении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445454/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-postgresql-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-python) говорили что лучше всего использовать класс, и вот я сделал так как в этом обращении

Comment: По поводу классов соглашусь с Сергеем. Вам не нужно делать один класс для работы с бд. Вам нужно сделать класс для отдельных сущностей, чтоб потом не дублировать код: получения, удаления, изменения например того же пользователя. Как и говорилось в том обращении на которое вы ссылались - вам достаточно сделать классы для каждой сущности: User, Product, Category  и т.д. И в них уже методы получения, удаления и т.д.

Comment: А еще лучше посмотрите что из себя представляют sqlalchemy и gino. Там есть orm, что даст хороший плюс к удобству.